# TableCalendar only shows dots on selected day

Tags: flutter, dart, table-calendar

I have a calendar like this

```dart
TableCalendar<Task>(
                onDaySelected: (date, date2) {
          onDateChanged!(date2);
        },
        selectedDayPredicate: (day) => isSameDay(dateSelected, day),
        calendarStyle: const CalendarStyle(
          markersAlignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
        ),
        eventLoader: (day) => _getEventsForDay(day),
        headerStyle: const HeaderStyle(
          formatButtonVisible: false,
        ),
        calendarFormat: CalendarFormat.month,
        currentDay: dateSelected,
        focusedDay: dateSelected,
        startingDayOfWeek: StartingDayOfWeek.monday,

        firstDay: DateTime.utc(2010, 10, 16),
        // registered on
        lastDay: DateTime.now().add(const Duration(days: 1000)),
      ),
```

And the problem is, it only shows the dots for the events, when i selected that date.
[image]

[image]

I want the dots to be visible for all the days of the month event if they are note selected,

Here is how i returned the venets:

```
List<Task> _getEventsForDay(DateTime day) {
   return allEvents.where((element) => DateTime(day.year, day.month, day.day).isSameDate(element.nextScheduledAt)).toList();
  }
```

Comment: The events are assembled according to the `eventLoader` property, you could add the code of the `_getEventsForDay(day)` method.

Comment: the problem is if i click any other date which has events it will also show dots. so for all the dates i have events on, it shows the dots as long as that particular day is selected.

i added the code for the function, but i am not sure it will help a lot.

Comment: What does `isSameDate` do?
See the list of events is returned based on calendar days, eventLoader is called with all days of the selected month starting from firstDay and based on the selected month. See this tableCalendar [example](https://github.com/aleksanderwozniak/table_calendar/blob/master/example/lib/pages/events_example.dart) for events.

Comment: @Diana can you include what `onDateChanged` does?

Comment: @mmcdon20 riiight. i was sorting them in on datechange only to get the ones fot day.... THANKS!!! now I got It!